# Avoiding require(../../../..) relative paths with grunt mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

When unit testing, I tend to have a directory called `test` at the top of my project structure, with the directory structure mimicking the source code that is to be tested. However, these directories can get quite deep, for example

`app/src/js/models/User.js`

with perhaps a test in

`test/app/src/js/models/User.js`.

Now, when I want to include the `User.js` module, I use `require('../../../../../app/src/js/models/Users.js')` which is very cumbersome.

Ideally, I would like to use `require('/app/src/js/models/User.js')` or perhaps even `require('User.js')`.

Is this possible? I am using [grunt-mocha-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mocha-test), but I think the question is a more general one.

Comment: Well you can try putting your test file in `test/models/User.js` instead of `test/app/src/js/models/User.js` then you can require it with `require('../../app/src/js/models/User.js')`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options you could use. Your best bet would probably be to use some npm module, for example [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-require). Search the npm registory for *require*, there are tons of options so choose whichever suits your needs.

Alternatively, you could write some helper function that does something similar.

If you were looking for some native way (built-in to Node.js) to achieve this, sadly there are none. You will have to use either a custom function or an npm module to do this in some nice, reusable way.